# Display Semantic UI React Search results by category?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Looking at the docs, example code given, and trying it out on their site. It seems like Semantic UI's (React) Search by Category module displays the results that match a given "title" with the input value, while providing which category they belong to. I was wondering if there was any way to display any results that match a given "category" or "title" with the given input value?

Comment: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/search/#types-category Doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include `"category"` in `searchFields` when building the element. You can even declare other keys in the source dictionaries and reference those in `searchFields`. It just won't display the extra attribute:

```
$('.ui.search').search({
  type: 'category',
  // [...]
  searchFields: ['title', 'description', 'category', 'keywords'],
});
```